# F# Fable and bootstrap modals

Tags: f#, bootstrap-modal, fable-f#

How can I create modal in Fable, it should work as normal Bootstrap modal.

```
div[Id "userOverview"; ClassName "modal fade"; Role "dialog"; TabIndex -1.; AriaLabelleddBy "userOverviewTile"][
  div[ClassName "model-dialog"; Role "document"][
    div[ClassName "model-content"][
      div[ClassName "modal-header"][
        button[ClassName "close"; DataDismiss "modal"; AriaLabel "Close"][
          span[AriaHidden "true"][!! "$times;"]
        ]
        h4[ClassName "modal-title"; Id "userOverviewTitle"][!! "User Overview"]
      ]
      div[ClassName "modal-body"][
        table[ClassName "table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive"][
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
          tr[][
            td[ClassName "w200 text-rigth"][!! "E-mail"]
            td[][!! "Lorem@ipsum.co"]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      div[ClassName "modal-footer"][
        button[Type "button"; ClassName "btn btn-default btn-lg"; DataDismiss "modal"][!! "Close"]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

In this example i get the following errors

```
error FSHARP: The value or constructor 'AriaLabelleddBy' is not defined  
error FSHARP: The value or constructor 'DataDismiss' is not defined
error FSHARP: The value or constructor 'AriaLabel' is not defined
error FSHARP: The value or constructor 'AriaHidden' is not defined
```

Is there another way?

Comment: It looks as though you are using Suave.Expiremental? Right? Where did you get this code from?

Comment: This part of code i wrote, creating modal from html design, I m pretty new in fable or f# overall so I m not sure what the issue is :/

Comment: Can you show us what modules you're `open`ing? Fable is just a F# -> JS compiler so we don't have enough information about which libraries you're using.

Comment: open Elmish

open Fable.Core

open Fable.Core.JsInterop

open Fable.Helpers.React

open Fable.Helpers.React.Props

open Helpers

open Fable.PowerPack
open Fable.PowerPack.Fetch.Fetch_types
open Fable.Import.Browser
open Fable.Import.ReactBoootstrapTreeview
open Fable.Import.Download

Comment: The first two errors look like typos. Are you sure they're supposed to exist?

Comment: If these attributes do not exist, try instead to replace for example AriaLabelleddBy "userOverviewTile" by Attribute "aria-labelledby" "userOverviewTile". Or perhaps attribute?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that these attributes are not defined by default on `React.Props.HTMLAttr` however you can extend the interface by implementing the following in your project.

```
 type HTMLAttr = 
     | [<CompiledName("data-dismiss")>] DataDismiss of string
     | [<CompiledName("aria-label")>] AriaLabel of string
     interface IHTMLProp
```

Obviously you can extend this union to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the custom attribute to set attributes not defined in Fable.React. eg. for ArialLabel:

```
div [ ..
    HTMLAttr.Custom ("aria-label","Close")
] [
    ....
]
```